# Classpath issue using XPathFactory

Tags: java, classpath

I keep getting the following exception on one of our live servers (the others running the same code seem ok):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: XPathFactory#newInstance() failed to create an XPathFactory for the default object model: http://java.sun.com/jaxp/xpath/domwith the XPathFactoryConfigurationException: javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactoryConfigurationException: No XPathFctory implementation found for the object model: http://java.sun.com/jaxp/xpath/dom
 at javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory.newInstance(XPathFactory.java:67)
```

I'm pretty sure that I have the Xalan and Saxon jars in the classpath (using IBM Java 1.5).

Do you have any Ideas what else could be wrong?

**Edit:**

That's the code that causes the Problem:

```
            XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
```

And it's running on a custom web server that's roughly based on the catalina engine.

Comment: Can you write the code that caused the error ?

Comment: What kind of environment are you running in?  Tomcat?  What version?

Comment: i know this adds nothing to the discussion, but the javadoc of the newInstance method explicitly says "this method will never fail" ... heh! (http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/apidocs/javax/xml/xpath/XPathFactory.html#newInstance())

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer myself: The problem is the combination of using Java 5 and having an option

```
-Djava.endorsed.dirs
```

set to a directory that contained the xalan.jar.

Once removed everything works again.

Answer (score 7):

You need to add the appropriate .jar in your classpath. In my case I used the Saxon-HE library.

[There exists a bug in Saxon9 you maybe run into like me.](https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/1944)

The bug has been corrected in version 9.5.1.5. So you may download the [latest Saxon 9 HE](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: You don't necessarily have to update from Saxon 9.1 B..  the offending class is not resident in the main jar, but in the auxiliary saxon-xpath.jar
If your project doesn’t utilise XPath expressions from Java, simply omit this jar from my class path - all XSLT transformation functionality seems to still work fine

Comment: Ran into the exact same thing. Upgrade to saxon > 9.5.1.4 worked! Thanks for sharing!

Comment: @Francis Your point of removing saxon-xpath.jar worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have the appropriate xml-apis.jar and xerces jars in your classpath for the version of xalan that you are using (check the release notes for what, exactly, you need).
Also make sure you don't have multiples as the xercesImpl.jar, xml-apis.jar and xalan.jar need to be in sync.

Comment: What do you mean by "in sync" - how do you know what versions sync up with each other?